# App doesn't work after using Kivy/Buildozer

Tags: python, kivy, buildozer

I use `buildozer android debug deploy run` to install my app on my android and my app installs but I can't run it on my phone
Here is my .spec file I got spam error so I send link to google drive

https://docs.google.com/document/d/1Rn1xDuWcGSvZsDVLVKeGUdwOtRtE1nNzJd91EHYmXwM/edit?usp=drivesdk

I am new to kivy and buildozer so can you tell me what I am doing wrong or what else should I attach to this post.And also I use some python build in modules in my project. Do I have to add them in requirements?

Comment: I just saw that in my grep file on the bottom there is ```Unknown command I python```. Can this be the issue?

Comment: https://kivy.org/doc/stable/guide/android.html#debugging-your-application-on-the-android-platform

Comment: Most probably you are missing any requirement. You can run logcat to get the logs of your android (link given above by @inclement). You can check the logs to see what causing your app to crash. Also, you don't have to include build-in python modules in requirements.

Comment: ok so it says ```OSError: Label: File 'Fonts\\Roboto-Medium.ttf' not found``` is something with my ```source.include_exts = py,png,jpg,kv,atlas,txt,wav,ttf``` wrong?